# Magento Community Edition - 1.7 - Invalid Config File

Tags: magento

I'm having some issues with a Magento Plugin; whenever I try to view the "Main Website" function from store views, I get this error message. I'm really not sure what it causing it... Could someone please help me?

Thanks,

```
There has been an error processing your request
Invalid config field backend model: dpd/adminhtml_system_config_backend_shipping_dpdclassic_tablerate

Trace:
#0 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#4 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#5 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#6 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#7 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /html/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /html/magento/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you for your support!

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is basically telling you that a system configuration field added by your module is trying to use a backend model (for handling the setting's value) that either doesn't exist, is broken or incompatible with your system.

For the sake of a sanity check, ensure you've cleared your cache after installing the module. Even if you have done it, do it again. This error can easily be caused by a stale cache during module installation.

Past that, you could use [`n98-magerun`](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) to check that the class name resolves correctly. If you run this:

```
n98-magerun dev:class:lookup model dpd/adminhtml_system_config_backend_shipping_dpdclassic_tablerate
```

... you should expect it to resolve to a PHP class. If it's broken it will tell you that the class doesn't exist.

Other things you can try:

- Clear your cache again
- Remove the module and re-install it
- If you installed this module with Magento Connect, disable the compiler and clear your cache again
- Contact whoever wrote the module and ask for their help

I can't give you a more definitive solution since you haven't shared any of your code (and this site is for people looking for help in debugging their code).

Good luck!

Comment: Although your answer is helpful, I came to the conclusion it would be best to export all my data and begin to import in to a newer version of Magento; this is because there are so many issues with our core files; our previous tech guy (Who wasn't very good); messed around a lot with the core files (Naughty...) and as such we have a lot of problems with the core functions of the Magento installation. But I will keep your post for future reference should I run into a similar issue. Thanks :-)